# Need to calculate difference between two dates in months

Tags: javascript, datetime

I am calculating a difference between two dates in months but not a single of the existing solutions seems to work for me. What I need is the replica of the Excel datedif formula - I am giving a result of js script vs Excel formula below.

**Option #1** doesn't work because it rounds up the month_dif result i.e. when the difference in days is more than 15 days, the function rounds up the result.
[image: Option1]

**Option #2** doesn't work for me because it gives a rough estimate.
[image: Option2]

Code for option (1)

```
var month_dif = dateDiff(reg_date, dates, "m")
```

Code for option (2)

```
var diff = Math.ceil(dates.getTime() - reg_date.getTime());
var secs = Math.floor(diff/1000);
var mins = Math.floor(secs/60);
var hours = Math.floor(mins/60);
var days = Math.floor(hours/24);
var month_dif = Math.floor(days/30);
```

Comment: Thank you, Eddie, sorry for the extra work for you!

Comment: Saying that you want the same results as in Excel is not enough of a specification, certainly not enough for a question posted to StackOverflow.  Can you describe the behavior you want?  How is it affected by Leap Days?  How about changes in Summer Time/Daylight Savings Time?

Comment: Hi Scott, thank you for the reply. It should take into consideration the leap year and the different number of days in a month.

Comment: The point is *how* is it supposed to take those into consideration? What is `2012-02-29 - 2011-02-28` or `2012-02-29 - 2011-03-01` or `2013-03-01 - 2012-02-29` and is that last different from `2013-03-01 - 2012-02-28` or `2012-03-01 - 2012-03-01`?  What happens when `2019-11-15` is an hour short of 31 days later than `2019-10-15` (due to Daylight Savings)?  In other words, *what are your requirements?*  It doesn't necessarily have to be the full algorithm, but enough to help us understand what you're looking for.

Comment: I am not sure I follow this part - 'What is 2012-02-29 - 2011-02-28 or 2012-02-29 - 2011-03-01 or 2013-03-01 - 2012-02-29 and is that last different from 2013-03-01 - 2012-02-28 or 2012-03-01 - 2012-03-01?' Are you asking the meaning of the calculation?

Comment: What answers do you expect from those?  How many months should be reported between a Leap Day in one year and March 1 of the year before?  How about between Leap Day and February 28 of the year before?  Etc.  I'm looking for what you mean by the difference in months.  Today is April 29.  In two days it will be May 1.  Is the difference between those two dates zero months or one month?  And between May 31 and today?  Is that one month or two?